# Can't find anything wrong with my selection sort code in C, but the code won't work

Tags: c, selection-sort

I'm a complete beginner in C, and I'm trying to learn how to do this selection sort algorithm to create an ascending list. But for some reason it doesn't run, and I can't seem to figure out why for an entire morning?

please tell me how I can fix it?

```
int main() {

    int x, i, j, tempt, min;
    int array[] = { 2,9,15,7,5,3,11,8,4 };
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < (size - 1); i++)
    {
        min = i;

        for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] < array[min])
            {
                min = j;
            }
            if (min != i)
            {
                tempt = array[i];
                array[i] = array[min];
                array[j] = tempt;
            }

        }
        for (i = 0; i < (size); i++) {
            printf("%d\n", array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I got

```
2
9
15
7
5
3
11
8
4

--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.02851 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Take a look at where the for loop is when the code is nicely formatted. When it modifies `i` what happens to the loop it is inside? Maybe you want to print the array after all of the sorting is done or if you want to print it on each iteration you need to use a different variable for the counter.

Comment: Don't re-use `i` for two different loop counter... There's LOTS of available letters in the alphabet... Go big and use a different letter for the printing loop... THEN, move the printing loop OUTSIDE of the outer sorting loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:-

First, You are using `i` inside the primary loop that you are using to sort.
For example, let's think that:

1. your loop started with `i=0;`
2. your `min` got the value of `i` which is `0`
3. now the second loop that uses `j` ran and did it's work.
4. now your control will shift to the third loop. where you are printing the array. Since you have written it inside the main for loop of your program, it can change `i`. It will start with `i`'s initial value which is `0` and print the values of array till `i<size`. So, we can say at the end of this loop your `i` will be equal to `size`. Now the value of `i` is equal to `size`. Now the main for loop will check the condition if `i<size-1` and it's false and the main for loop will not run and your program will exit after your main for loop ran for just once.

Second Problem is that even if you put the last for loop out and print it after the whole sorting(). Still, when you replace the `array[min]` variable with the `array[i]` variable then technically the `min` index also changes because you changed the variable at this index and send the minimum variable at another location through swapping. So you should change your min to j after each swapping.
After considering all these possibilities, your code should look like this:-

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int x, i, j, tempt, min;
    int array[] = { 4,9,15,7,5,3,11,8,4 };
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < (size - 1); i++)
    {
        min = i;

        for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] < array[min])
            {
                min = j;
            }
            if (min != i)
            {
                tempt = array[i];
                array[i] = array[min];
                array[j] = tempt;
                min=i;
            }

        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < (size); i++) {
            printf("%d\n", array[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: If you are swapping `array[i]` and `array[min]`, what should you assign `tempt` to after assigning `array[i] = array[min]`? (which one hasn't changed yet?)

Comment: Since we are checking if min is equal to `i` or not before entring the block, it means `j` is already equals to `min` if we have entered the block. So we can assign `array[min] = tempt` or `array[j]=tempt` and again we are changing the `min` to `i` after this array. Does this still not make sense to shift `array[i]` with either `array[min]` or `array[j]` because they are the same. Please let me know if I am wrong @DavidC.Rankin and @Fe2O3.

Comment: I am just trying to explain his own code to him. Not giving him the right answer but giving him the right direction. This answer is right though but still I wanted to show him how his program is working.

Comment: To swap `array[i]` and `array[min]`, you set temp equal to one of them, assign the other values, e.g. `array[i] = array[min];` and then you set the other to `tempt`. You have already assigned `array[i] = array[min];` ... so what remains is `array[min] = tempt;`. Now `array[i]` and `array[min]` have been swapped `:)` (and you don't need `min = i;` afterwards.)

Comment: I've deleted my wrong "wrong" comment... Confusing when values of "long lived" variables are used without consistency... Think about factoring the "swap" to its own function... Would one pass both `j` and `min` to that function?

Comment: Yes but the guy has already assigned `j` to `min`. so technically you can do `array[j] = tempt` too. I mean you are telling the right approach. I am trying to tell how can we change this approach to behave right.

Comment: You also need to move the close of your `j` loop after the `if (array[j] < array[min]) { min = j; }` so the swap is OUTSIDE of the `j` loop `:)` [Your code updated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76792682/3422102)

Comment: Here is a [More Compact Version](https://paste.opensuse.org/1bd9ad9e0374) to compare to. (and I like your explanation -- it just needs a little more work -- your formatting is really good -- just give it a bit more work -- and then drop another comment for me and I'll come back and vote for it)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You are right but try to run this code: [code](https://onecompiler.com/c/3zfxh5krw) I think it explains how keeping this inside the loop makes it more optimal.

Comment: I mean it just don't swap a single variable at a time it also sends bigger elements back with each iteration

Comment: @ThugLife okay it works perfectly now. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: The only problem with the swap inside the loop is efficiency. Items are considered for swap ans swapped many more times that required. Definition [Selection Sort - Wikipedia - C implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). There are so many sort routines, when you change one slightly, you may very will have something other than a "selection sort".

Answer (score 2):

The correct code is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int x,i,j,tempt,min;
  int array[] = {2,9,15,7,5,3,11,8,4};
  int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);

  for(i = 0; i < (size-1); i++) {
    min = i;

    for(j = i+1; j < size; j++) {
      if(array[j] < array[min]) {
        min = j;    
      }
    }

    if(min != i) {
      tempt = array[i];
      array[i] = array[min];  
      array[min] = tempt;
    }
  }

  for(i = 0;i < size;i++){
    printf("%d\n",array[i]);
  }
}
```

The main issues with this original version:

The swap logic was inside the inner loop, so it was swapping on every iteration instead of just once after finding the minimum.
It was swapping array[i] and array[j] instead of array[i] and array[min].
The minimum index 'min' was not being reset, so it would keep finding the same minimum each outer iteration.

By moving the swap out of the loop, swapping with the min index, and resetting min, your final code fixes these issues to implement the selection sort properly.

Comment: Or put another way, the OP had the closing brace for the `j` loop after the swap when they should have closed the `j` loop after `if(array[j] < array[min]) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Move the block:

   ```
   if (min != i)
   {
       tempt = array[i];
       array[i] = array[min];
       array[j] = tempt;
   }
   ```

outside the inner loop.

2. fix the typo; `min` should be used instead of `j` for swapping:

   ```
   if (min != i)
   {
       tempt = array[i];
       array[i] = array[min];
       array[min] = tempt;
   }
   ```
3. Move the printing loop outside of the outer loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < (size); i++) {
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

4. Remove `x`, it is not being used anywhere.

Your code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int i, j, tempt, min;
    int array[] = { 2,9,15,7,5,3,11,8,4 };
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < (size - 1); i++)
    {
        min = i;

        for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] < array[min])
            {
                min = j;
            }

        }
        if (min != i)
        {
            tempt = array[i];
            array[i] = array[min];
            array[min] = tempt;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < (size); i++) {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```